# How to avoid global style tags with Webpack CSS loaders?

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader

When using webpack with various CSS loaders, looks like it creates a new style tag whenever styling is used within react components.

For example, one of my dependencies is using antd components so all and styles show up in the head. This creates a conflict with styles used by elsewhere.

Are there other way to handle this so instead of creating a global style tag, these css are applied locally to components?

[image]

My webpack configuration for css related settings is as follows

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [{
    loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
  }, {
    loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
  }, {
    loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
  }]
},
{
  test: /\.css/,
  loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
}, {
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  use: "babel-loader",
  exclude: /node_modules/
}, {
  test: /\.less$/,
  use: [{
    loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
  }, {
    loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
  }, {
    loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
  }, {
    loader: "less-loader" // compiles Less to CSS
  }]
}
```